# Can't run two times execl

Tags: c, unistd.h

If I try to executes these commands:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    execl("/bin/echo","echo","list ","of", "files:\n",NULL);
    execl("/bin/ls","ls","-al",NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Only the first one gets executed, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

execl REPLACES the current process - it's not a subroutine. You might try using `system()` instead.

Comment: `system` is bad. Just `fork` before the `execl`.

Comment: But fork will split it into two processes, which will run in parallel but will both display output to the same file handle. This could conceivably result in the heading being displayed in the middle of the output.

I agree that system is bad, but I don't see how fork is any better.

Comment: One process (normally the child) calls `execl` instead of doing the same thing as the parent, so no, you do not get 2 copies of the output (unless perhaps you ignore the failure of `execl` and don't immediately `_exit` when it fails).

Answer (score 4):

Because as soon as you run `exec*()` **your application stops existing**. If you want to run more than one external process then you'll need to `fork()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fork first.

Try running

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( vfork() == 0 )
        execl("/bin/echo","echo","list ","of", "files:\n",NULL);
    if( vfork() == 0 )
        execl("/bin/ls","ls","-al",NULL);
    return 0;
}
```